# Apache2 block .php file endings

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

i don't know much about .htaccess file and apache2 configuration. I found this peace of code online and it works, i have set a 404 in the htaccess file, how to redirect a user to 404 if he puts .php in the url?

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The Solution:
.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

and then in the php file(i have a init file which gets called every time a website gets opend):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php")){//If in here it has .php ending}
```

and redirect this to your error site.